How can I approximate the P3-RGB value 555nm-looking light
There are common methods for srgb but I couldn't find one for P3

Some context to your question would help. As would an example of what you are referring to for srgb. Please try to improve your question. Thank you.

Just a short answer. I've no time for full details, but it may gives you inputs to do proper calculations.
You said: approximate, so I would go in Wikipedia and look e.g. colour space, where you can find classical chromaticity diagram, in such case:

The outer line are the spectral colours (+ the line of purples on bottom). If you look, the spectral line has blue numbers, that are the wavelength (in nm), so you can estimate where 555 is and find the coordinates of CIE xy (often we use the missing coordinate as Brightness, but on border of gamut you must take what you get).
Now you get the chromaticity you want to reproduce. So let's check (also in Wikipedia) the data of Display-P3 (which I think it is a derivation of DCI-P3), so https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DCI-P3
You get the chromaticities of the 3 primaries of P3, and white point. Now it is up to you to find the point on the line between green and red which approximate with the desired x,y. Usually two methods are used: one is the nearest point (so perpendicular point), the second is the point which intersect the line which pass from your point with white point, and the line red-green. Of just look chromaticity diagram of P3 (maybe in gamut page or googling), and visually you select a x,y coordinate.
Now things get more complex (because I think someone refactor Wikipedia pages). We have x,y and we want R,G,B in Display-P3. Often we work with intermediate colour space XYZ (which you should find transformation from/to all colour spaces). E.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIE_1931_color_space#CIE_xy_chromaticity_diagram_and_the_CIE_xyY_color_space you know hot to convert to X,Y,Z  Select Y (brightness) as 1 or 255 (as you prefer). Later we will scale so that no R,G,B values are above 255 (so maximum brightness for a chromaticity).
What I do not find quickly it is how to convert XYZ to R,G,B in Display-P3 but you should find the data, or just the general conversion with R,G,B (with primary chromaticities given as parameter). Just remember in such step that we worked in linear space, so you need to apply gamma (and possibly scale values before that: same scale value for the 3 channels and always on linear space else hue will change).
Note: and thinking again, possibly it is an overkill (but colour libraries should have functions for all steps, but maybe the wavelength chromaticity)
Note 2: but the thinking again gave me a better solution: go to CIE standard observer (1931), and you can download the CIE-RGB data per wavelength (raw data of experiment and interpolation. You have negative values, but it is ok. So how you just linear transform from one RGB to an other RGB colour space, and apply gamma.

Using [colour], it is possible to do the conversion directly using the spectral power distribution. Assuming that there is only irradiance at 555nm, the DCI-P3 value for 555nm would be as follows:
[ 0.35094129  1.20038913 -0.05632848]
import colour

RGB_colourspace = "DCI-P3"
sd_laser = colour.sd_zeros()
sd_laser.name = "Laser - 555nm"
sd_laser[555] = 1

XYZ_laser = colour.sd_to_XYZ(sd_laser)
RGB_laser = colour.XYZ_to_RGB(XYZ_laser, RGB_colourspace)
print(RGB_laser)


colour.plotting.plot_sds_in_chromaticity_diagram_CIE1931(
    sd_laser,
    chromaticity_diagram_callable_CIE1931=colour.plotting.plot_RGB_colourspaces_in_chromaticity_diagram_CIE1931,
    colourspaces=RGB_colourspace,
)



It is also possible to use a gaussian function that would reduce colorimetric purity as a function of its FWHM:
[ 23.11752882  52.98846204  -1.83529997]
sd_gaussian = colour.sd_gaussian(555, 20, method="FWHM")
sd_gaussian.name = "Gaussian - 555nm - 20FWHM"

XYZ_gaussian = colour.sd_to_XYZ(sd_gaussian)
RGB_gaussian = colour.XYZ_to_RGB(XYZ_gaussian, RGB_colourspace)
print(RGB_gaussian)

colour.plotting.plot_single_sd(sd_gaussian)

colour.plotting.plot_sds_in_chromaticity_diagram_CIE1931(
    sd_gaussian,
    chromaticity_diagram_callable_CIE1931=colour.plotting.plot_RGB_colourspaces_in_chromaticity_diagram_CIE1931,
    colourspaces=RGB_colourspace,
)




I've recently added some functionality to my C# / .NET Unicolour library to make try to make this kind of thing easier and more accessible, using a "WXY" space that I've put together.
This example shows how you can use Unicolour to approximate an RGB value of 555 nm light. It defines a colour using a wavelength at full purity, and then maps that colour into the Display P3 gamut by reducing the purity. Note that you need to choose a suitable relative luminance - this example uses 0.5.
const double step = 0.01; // reduce for greater accuracy

var displayP3 = new Configuration(RgbConfiguration.DisplayP3);

// WXY = dominant wavelength, excitation purity, relative luminance
var (w, x, y) = (555, 1.0, 0.5);
var colour = new Unicolour(displayP3, ColourSpace.Wxy, w, x, y);
while (!colour.IsInDisplayGamut)
{
    x -= step;
    colour = new Unicolour(displayP3, ColourSpace.Wxy, w, x, y);
}

Console.WriteLine(colour.Hex); // #78D405


(I've written more details about WXY and gamut mapping here, and mention 2 other ways to gamut map: very simple but inaccurate clipping of RGB values, and the complex chroma-reduction mapping of the CSS specification. Choose the mapping technique best suited for your needs.)
